# Remove a users reaction from fetchMessage? - Discord JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a question for Discord.js.
How would I remove a specific user's reaction from a message?

I have tried to do so with this code:

```
// Now known as 'messages.fetch'.
message.channel.fetchMessage(MessageID).then(m => {
   m.reactions.remove(UserID);
});
```

But it doesn't remove the user's reaction at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One user can add multiple reactions. Which one should be removed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this question is getting a lot of attraction, I decided to post what worked for me

**Remove Specific User's Specific Reaction**

```
// Channel = the channel object of the message's original channel
// MessageID = ID of the message, if hard coding, put around quotations eg: "1234"

const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(MessageID);

msg.reactions.resolve("REACTION EMOJI, 
REACTION OBJECT OR REACTION ID").users.remove("ID OR OBJECT OF USER TO REMOVE");
```

*Note: If using an older version of discord.js, simply replace `channel.messages.fetch` with `channel.fetchMessage`*

Answer (score 4):

The chosen option works, I would like to explain it. You need to grab the MessageReaction object from the message for the reaction you want to remove. How you do that depends on your code, in my case I was working with a reaction collector so on my collect call I already had the MessageReaction.

You then need to access the users property (a ReactionUserManager object). With this object, you can call .remove().

Code is below:

```
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
...
// delete the reaciton
reaction.users.remove(user.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`message.reactions` is a collection of `messageReactions`. I think you need to loop through the collection and then remove the `messageReaction` required.

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID).map(r => r).then(message => {
  message.reactions.forEach(reaction => reaction.remove(UserID))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions) for reactions you can see it is a `Collection`, and it mentions that they are mapped by *reaction* ID's , and not the user ID's. The way you could remove them is get the reaction, filter the users and then maybe do something with that? I'm not sure how to remove *those* specifically, but that should get you the users, then filter that to the ID you want.

```js
message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID).then(msg = m.reactions.get(reactionID).users); // Gets the users that reacted to a certain emote, I think.
```