# How do I remove a reaction from a message by a specific user in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'd like to remove a reaction from a specific user for a message I've fetched. However I couldn't get it to work (probably because I'm a weeb who can't do Javascript), so it'd be nice if I could get some help :)

I tried looking around such as [this][Remove a users reaction from fetchMessage? - Discord JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379469/remove-a-users-reaction-from-fetchmessage-discord-js) thread, however it returned as map was undefined.

The most recent I came up with was this:

```js
            var messageEmbed = message.channel.fetchMessage('637189841418846208')
                .catch(console.error);
                messageEmbed.reactions.remove(message.author.id)
```

I want it to remove the reaction but instead I got the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"reactions" is a collection of reactions, therefore you need to first find the specific reaction you are looking for, this example fetches the first reaction on the message and attempts to remove a user from the reaction.

```
let messageEmbed = message.channel.fetchMessage('637189841418846208')
.catch(console.error);
messageEmbed.reactions.first().remove(message.author.id)
```

There are many other ways to search within a collection for a specific reaction, a general one is the .get() method witch in this case will search for the reaction based on it's ID

```
messageEmbed.reactions.get("REACTION ID")
```

To see all of the methods available see, [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), [Reaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=remove).

Comment: I tried what you said however it returned with an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Does the message in question have any reactions when you ran the code? If so, it might be worth adding a ```console.log(messageEmbed.reactions)``` to check if there's any reactions at all, or even better, check if it's fetching the right message.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently it didn't fetch the message properly! Everything else works great!

Comment: Great to see that it worked! In situations like these it's always good to debug from the bottom up, so starting with if the data you are processing was found in the first place, up to the actual processing.