# how to remove reaction by specified user?

Tags: discord.js

I have this code but it's removing all reactions on message, but i want to remove reactions by specified user id

```
channel.messages.fetch('981767936949747722').then(function (message) { 
message.reactions.cache.forEach(reaction => reaction.remove())
});
```

Comment: Use `message.reactions.cache.forEach(reaction => reaction.users.remove("user id"));` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a users reaction from fetchMessage? - Discord JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379469/remove-a-users-reaction-from-fetchmessage-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

```js
channel.messages.fetch('981767936949747722').then(function (message) { 
message.reactions.cache.forEach(reaction => reaction.user.remove("304541381798658048")) // Replace 304541381798658048 by your user ID
});
```

This code should work.